# Mysql slow query on large table

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

With Mysql 5.6.10, I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `es_user_action` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `work_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action` tinyint(2) NOT NULL COMMENT '10, 20, 30, 40',
  `action_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `apply_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_display_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `scout_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `register_datetime_sorting` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_pending` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '2' COMMENT '1: paid, 2: free',
  `has_response` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `response_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_shown` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1',
  `source` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_company_work` (`user_id`,`work_id`,`company_id`,`apply_id`,`source`),
  KEY `IDX_2` (`company_id`,`is_shown`,`apply_status`,`apply_id`,`work_id`,`action_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=436896779 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The full query I want to perform on the table would be the following:

```
SELECT
    `id` AS `seqNo`,
    `company_id` AS `companyId`,
    `work_id` AS `workId`,
    `action` AS `userActionType`,
    `action_time` AS `userActionDatetime`,
    `is_pending`,
    `apply_status`,
    `action_id`,
    `source`,
    `user_id` AS `userId`,
    `apply_display_id`  
FROM
    `es_user_action`
WHERE
    `company_id` = 449664
    AND `is_shown` = 1 
    AND `apply_status` = 1
    AND `apply_id` = 0
    AND `action_time` >= '2021-01-05 15:56:14'   
ORDER BY
    is_pending ASC,
    action ASC,
    score DESC,
CASE
        source 
        WHEN "entenshoku" THEN
        action_time 
    END DESC,
CASE
        
        WHEN source <> "entenshoku" THEN
        action_time 
END ASC
    LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

The table has around 15 million rows and the following query takes around 15 seconds. The query becomes very slow.
Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**

This is the explain query result:
[image: explain query]

Comment: Step 1 is always `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see how your query is processed.

Comment: Having a `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` is going to be a drag on performance here as I'm pretty sure that means no index can be used, so it's a manual resort. Does removing any of these conditions help speed things up?

Comment: Also try using EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see if indices are always used if necessary add them

Comment: @tadman Not really true ... but yes it might mean that an index cannot be used for the sorting step.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It has to evaluate this row by row, doesn't it? I've never seen `CASE` used in an `ORDER BY` clause before. The very idea sounds like trouble.

Comment: Is this all to sort one type of thing one way, and another thing the other way? You might want to move the `CASE` into the main `SELECT` and have a result column you can straight-up sort on, like `CASE source WHEN "..." action_time ELSE -action_time END AS action_time_sort` That too seems strange. Is the intention here to list in either chronological or reverse chronological for a particular set of records? If so, maybe composing a query with either `ASC` or `DESC` in it would work way better.

Comment: @tadman I have updated the explain query result

Comment: @tadman This is the requirement, I can't change ...hmmmm

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen only I remove all Order by queries, it will be faster

Comment: Dump an index on source and report back `ALTER TABLE  es_user_action ADD KEY source;`

Comment: @Mihai sorry, no effect

Comment: How many rows does your query selects?

Comment: @Akina no, about 2,5 million records, about 1/7

Comment: Test execution time with indices usage disabled (IGNORE INDEX).

Comment: @Akina very slow, ~20s

Comment: That `with filesort` is the problem here. The only way to get rid of that is to make your `ORDER BY` align with an index. In this form it can't. Where it *does* match an index queries like this become fairly trivial even on large sets. Without that it *must* fetch all matching rows and bash them around in an expensive filesort.

Comment: @tadman I have tried but no effect...

Comment: You really haven't explained the intent behind the unusual use of `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause, nor why that couldn't be stripped out entirely. As a test, does switching all that case-stuff into something simple like `score DESC, action_time DESC` make it perform better?

Comment: It's also worth noting that MySQL 5.6 isn't really all that great when it comes to performance, especially on things like this where the optimizer gives up and goes home. 5.7 made some gains, but 8.0 is in many cases dramatically better. You may want to at least test on those versions to see if there's any notable differences. Upgrading may not be easy, but if this is a critical problem it might be worth it.

Comment: also to add to @tadman 's comment `LIMIT <large_set_number>` might be  slow which could result into a disk based temporary table with lots of random disk i/o write and reads on tables with millions of records you might want to consider to use `AND id >= <start> AND id < <limit>` in the `WHERE` clause instead

Comment: 20s is not "too slow" while compare with initial 15s. Now I agreed fully with tadman that the sorting stage is a problem. Now the question: you sort by `is_pending ASC` firstly... The name and its datatype hints that it is a boolean column. Your query returns over 2kk rows, but your LIMIT selects 100 rows only, and I suspect that all of them have the same value in `is_pending` column. Is it: in general? always due to data statistic?

Comment: @Akina, not all, is_pending has 2 values is 1 or 0 and I want sort them first. Do you have any idea to optimize?

Comment: I see... do you want to say that there is less than 100 rows with `is_pending = 0` in the output, in 2.5kk rows selected without the limitation? If so then you may try to divide your query to 2 separate queries, with the condition by `is_pending` (instead of sorting), limit the query with `is_pending = 1` condition, then UNION ALL and final sorting/limiting.

Comment: I don't think 8.0 has any tricks that will help over 5.6.

Comment: @Akina - I think the UNION trick will hurt more than help -- because 2.5kk rows still need to be touched.  What _might_ help is to query `WHERE is_pending=0`; if at least 100 rows are returned, then the task is finished, and some optimization was achieved.  But if <100 are returned, then it must do _more_ work to get some rows with `is_pending=1`.

Comment: @RickJames *But if <100 are returned* Do not forget that one expression is moved from ORDER BY to WHERE, and it may be included into the index. Additionally the length of sorting expression decreases which will decrease the time needed for sorting. And if <100 rows is returned them we may apply the same method but using `WHERE ... AND ((is_pending = 0) OR (action = 10)` or `WHERE ... AND ((is_pending = 0) OR (action IN (10, 20))`... And maybe it is not critical that one time per month the query will return 98 rows instead of 100...

Comment: Alas, the Optimizer is not smart enough to "short-circuit" a `UNION ALL` with an `ORDER BY` after it.

Comment: @Akina, RickJames I can't remove the limit query because I want to paginate

Answer (score 0):

```
  KEY `IDX_2` (`company_id`,`is_shown`,`apply_status`,`apply_id`,`work_id`,`action_time`)
```

`Work_id` is in the way of that index being effective for that `SELECT`.  Remove it.  That should speed up the query some.  Still the are too many columns and expressions involved in the `WHER` and `ORDER BY` to do much more to help.

Changing `BIGINTs` to smaller INT types will help some (by shrinking the table).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you have cannot work.

You have is a dynamically changing `ORDER BY`, depending on the value of `source`.  But which row's `source`?

If you could decide *before* issuing the query whether to scan `action_time` ascending or descending, *which* value of `source` would you pick?

Delete this Question, rewrite the query, then open another Question if you still have an issue.